# Error con PHP en Notice: Undefined index: btn1

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy probando un enviar un enviar correo y al momento de darle enviar me sale:

> Notice: Undefined index: btn1 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\index(login).php on line 48.

Estuve buscando por harto tiempo incluso copie un `if($_POST)`que tenia guardado y tampoco me funciono, quiza sea un error muy tonto pero no he podido encontrarlo.

```
<div class="modal-dialog text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="modal-content"><br>
                    <div class="">
                        <img src="img/user.png">
                    </div><br>
                    <!--FORM INICIO-->
                    <form class="col-12" method="POST" >
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtnombre" placeholder="nombre">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtcorreo" placeholder="correo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="btn1" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar"></input>
                        </div>

                        <?php 
                        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
                        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;    
                        $cnn = Conectar();                          
                        if($_POST['btn1']=="Guardar") {
                        function generateRandomString($length) {  
                        return substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);  
                        }                            
                        $randompass = generateRandomString(7);                      
                        $nombre=$_POST['txtnombre'];
                        $correo = $_POST['txtcorreo'];             
                        $sql="UPDATE `usuarios` SET`pass`='$randompass' WHERE mail ='$correo'";                       
                        echo $sql; mysql_query($sql,$cnn); 
                        echo "<script>alert('se han grabado los datos')</script>"; 
                        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
                        try {
                        //Server settings
                        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
                        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
                        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                        $mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';                 // SMTP username
                        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';                           // SMTP password
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

                        //Recipients
                        $mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'Tecnotec');
                        $mail->addAddress($correo, $nombre);// Add a recipient

                        //Content                                
                        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
                        $mail->Subject = 'Codigo de acceso';
                        $mail->Body    = "No compartir codigo de acceso con otros usuarios, el mal uso de este sera perjudicial para usted.   Su codigo de acceso es: ".$randompass;


                        $mail->send();
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                        Codigo de acceso enviado, por favor revise su correo electronico e ingrese el codigo en la casilla de abajo
                        </div>';
                        }catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo 'El codigo no se pudo enviar, error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
                                }

                        }
                        ?>


                    </form>
                    <!--FORM FIN-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: No pongas tu correo y tu password en las publicaciones pues cualquiera lo podria usar. He hecho una edición para ocultarlas pero aún así cambia la password inmediatamente por si alguien las ha copiado.

Comment: @JDev hay que reportarlo a ver si pueden borrar los datos, pues las versiones antiguas de la pregunta quedan en el historial de ediciones.

Answer (score 2):

Deberías asegurarte de que existe la variable "btn1", ya que nada más cargas la pagina sin mandar nada por post intentas acceder a algo que no existe:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn1']) $_POST['btn1']=="Guardar" ) {
    function generateRandomString($length) {  
    return substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que tu formulario no tiene un `action` para que recoger las variables.
Estas utiliza el `php` en el mismo que tu formulario.

Prueba a ponerlo así:

```
 <form class="col-12" method="POST"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

> Recuerda, si no hay un `action`, tiene que enviarse por `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no tengo idea de que paso, pero se soluciono, la cuestión es que intente lo que me dijeron ustedes pero no funciono luego de eso presione ctr+z para volver al estado original y PUM! funciono xd
Gracias de todas formas por responder a la pregunta